# Dropbox Delegate methods not being called

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, dropbox-api

I have a problem with the Dropbox API. I'm working on big app, which was started by another developer. Now I'm going to clean the code. All the Delegate Methods (loadedMetadata & Co.) were directly in the view. Now I want to extract them into their own class. So I created a DropboxService class with all the methods in it. So I have the view and call the method loadMetadata from the DropboxService. The method is called and woking fine. But the Delegate method loadedMetadata is never called.

What did I do wrong / what do I have to change to get this working correctly?

The Dropbox Service has the DBRestClientDelegate as a "Superclass" (don't know how it i exactly called)

```
@interface DropboxService : CloudProviderService <DBRestClientDelegate> {
}
```

Edit:

The Service is instantiated in the AppDelegate and is a variable there:

```
- (DropboxService *)getDropboxService {
    if (self.dropboxService == nil) {
        self.dropboxService = [[DropboxService alloc] init];
    }
    return self.dropboxService;
}
```

Greetings from Germany

Alexander

Comment: Could you provide the code where you instantiate your client and assign its delegate?

Comment: `DBRestClientDelegate` is not it's "superclass". You could say that `DropboxService` _adopts_ the `DBRestClientDelegate` _protocol_

Comment: fguchelaar: thanks
CarlVeazey: what do you mean with "Assign its delegate?"

Comment: Well you have to assign the request's delegate somewhere, where is it being set? like, `request.delegate = someobject;` what does the code around that look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also set the delegate after init

```
DBRestClient.delegate = self;
```

from this interface

```
@interface DBRestClient : NSObject { ... id<DBRestClientDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: the dropboxService does not yet have a Property called Delegate, should I create it? Of which type does it have to be?

Comment: A protocol needs to be "told" on which object it will trigger callbacks. That is achieved by assigning the delegate to that object. That is the step you are missing. There should be a delegate property somewhere.

Comment: The Dropbox Session has a delegate and this is the DropboxService


        DBSession *session = [DBSession alloc];
        [session initWithAppKey:CONSUMER_KEY appSecret:SECRET_KEY root:kDBRootDropbox];
        session.delegate = self; // DBSessionDelegate methods allow you to handle re-authenticating
        [DBSession setSharedSession:session];

Comment: @interface DBRestClient : NSObject { ...
    id<DBRestClientDelegate> delegate; ... this is the one you need to set.

Answer (score 0):

That header doesnt say that `DropboxService` is a sub-class of `DBRestClientDelegate`

it says that `DropboxService` conforms to the protocol of  `DBRestClientDelegate`

The Dropbox sample project explains all this, but you want to look for where you set up `DBRestClient` and make sure `DropboxService` is made the delegate of that instance.

This is what it looks like in my code which conforms to `DBRestClientDelegate`

```
- (DBRestClient*)restClient {
    if (restClient == nil) {
        restClient = [((DBRestClient *)[DBRestClient alloc]) initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
        restClient.delegate = self;
    }
    return restClient;
}
```

Comment: OK I found the error: In the view there was a restClient.delegate = self line left.... so the delegate was always set back to the view... I changed it and now it is working... Thanks!

Comment: could you please explain whet u did to resolve the problem because i have the same problem.